# Blocking a function after it has been used in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Im currently trying to implement a function into my PowerShell GUI which allows the user to "shorten" filenames in a specific folder.

The Problem is that if he presses the button twice by accident, the filename gets messed up. Is there a way to block the function after it has been used or is it just that my script isn't "smart" enough?

Original filename:

```
PM.KDP_client_provide_123_SE.xml
```

After one use:

```
PM.KDP_client1.xml
```

After more than one time:

```
p.xml
```

Here the code:

```
Try{
        Get-ChildItem -path K:\adm_spm_logdb_data\KDP\ErrorLog -ErrorAction Stop | Group-Object { $_.BaseName -replace 'provide.*$' } | ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_.Name
        $i = 1
        $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
            $_ | Rename-Item -NewName "$name$i$($_.Extension)"
            $i++
                }
            }
        }catch [System.Exception]{
        $listBox1.Items.Add("Error found.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you simply disable the button by setting its `enabled` property?

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm i changed the enabled property of the button now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) has the most logical idea from a User Experience point of view. If you don't want the use to be able to click the button again simply disable the button by toggling its enabled property.

Another approach would be to update your function so that it only isolated files that you want to be changed. So, for example, if you were only updating files that contained "provide" (guess based on your file name provided) changed you `Get-ChildItem` to only pull those types of files.

```
Get-ChildItem -path K:\adm_spm_logdb_data\KDP\ErrorLog -Filter "*provide*.xml" -ErrorAction Stop
```

I would opt for disabling the button though as that would not confuse the users.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your helped me a lot.

Comment: @MichaelM. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I ended up using a mix between the filter and enabled property :)

Comment: Sounds good. User gets the right experience and the filter only changes the files it is supposed to anyway. Less margin for error.